# How to check if list of variables have specific values?

Tags: r, validation, variables

I have a set of variables, say `x, y, z, temp, p, k....`
I have a test set of values, say

```
1, TRUE, "kuku", -1, 0.5, "high"...
```

I want to test if my set of variables have the values I have mentioned as example.

Let me show a simple example:

```
x <- 3
y <- 4
```

check if `x` and `y` values are in `c(3,4)`.

What I tried is `x & y %in% c(3,4)` but it doesn't do what I need.
Should I use any? 
I am looking for a smart one line solution or a trick, please advise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `all` and `c`, should give you what you want:

```
all(c(x, y) %in% c(3, 4))
#[1] TRUE
```

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, I need to wrap all my variables in a vector each time I want to check if they have their default values?

Comment: Either atomic vector or a list would work if that's what you mean yeah. Working with lists / atomic vectors is preferred in R anyway (as opposed to having multiple variables on the global environment).

Answer (score 1):

Put your variables in a list and your test values in another list, and let `%in%` take care of the rest:

```
x = "kuku"
y = 1
z = FALSE
vars = list(x, y, z)
vals = list(1, TRUE, "kuku", 2)
vals %in% vars
## [1]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  FALSE
```

The result is a vector of the same length as `vals` whose `i`th element indicates whether `vals[i]` can be found anywhere in `vars`.

To check if any or all values are in your variables, use `any` or `all`

```
any(vals %in% vars)
## [1] TRUE
all(vals %in% vars)
## [1] FALSE
```